# Poor video performance after amdgpu upgrade

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, opengl, amdgpu

I have a Radeon RX 7900 XTX on Ubuntu 22.04. It previously was running fine after installing `amdgpu-install_5.4.50406-1_all.deb`, before I decided to update to the latest `amdgpu-install_5.5.50502-1_all.deb` (July 2023); now I get poor framerates in games.

I used `sudo amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics,workstation,amf --vulkan=amdvlk,pro` to do the install. Prior to the install, my `glxinfo -B` looked like this:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: AMD (0x1002)
    Device: Radeon RX 7900 XTX (gfx1100, LLVM 15.0.3, DRM 3.48, 5.19.0-46-generic) (0x744c)
    Version: 22.3.0
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 24576MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
Memory info (GL_ATI_meminfo):
    VBO free memory - total: 21960 MB, largest block: 21960 MB
    VBO free aux. memory - total: 63924 MB, largest block: 63924 MB
    Texture free memory - total: 21960 MB, largest block: 21960 MB
    Texture free aux. memory - total: 63924 MB, largest block: 63924 MB
    Renderbuffer free memory - total: 21960 MB, largest block: 21960 MB
    Renderbuffer free aux. memory - total: 63924 MB, largest block: 63924 MB
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 24576 MB
    Total available memory: 88548 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 21960 MB
OpenGL vendor string: AMD
OpenGL renderer string: Radeon RX 7900 XTX (gfx1100, LLVM 15.0.3, DRM 3.48, 5.19.0-46-generic)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.3.0-devel
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.3.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.3.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

Afterwards it looks like this:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Memory info (GL_ATI_meminfo):
    VBO free memory - total: 24559 MB, largest block: 24559 MB
    VBO free aux. memory - total: 63972 MB, largest block: 63972 MB
    Texture free memory - total: 24559 MB, largest block: 24559 MB
    Texture free aux. memory - total: 63972 MB, largest block: 63972 MB
    Renderbuffer free memory - total: 24559 MB, largest block: 24559 MB
    Renderbuffer free aux. memory - total: 63972 MB, largest block: 63972 MB
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Radeon RX 7900 XTX
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 Core Profile Context 23.10.230614
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 Compatibility Profile Context 23.10.230614
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2.0 23.10.230614 
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

Seems suspicious that the `Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer)` has disappeared from `glxinfo -B`?

I've tried:

- Re-installing kisak Mesa drivers
- Reverting to the older amdgpu package: performance is back, `Extended renderer info` reappears.